# Airflow: Celery task failure

Tags: celery, airflow

I have airflow up and running but I have an issue where my task is failing in celery.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 52, in execute_command
    subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'airflow run airflow_tutorial_v01 print_hello 2017-06-01T15:00:00 --local -sd /usr/local/airflow/dags/hello_world.py' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 375, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 632, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 55, in execute_command
    raise AirflowException('Celery command failed')
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Celery command failed
```

it is a very basic DAG (taken from the hello world tutorial: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py).

Also I do not see any logs of my worker, I got this stack strace from the Flower web interface.

If I run manually on the worker node, the airflow run command mentionned in the stack trace it works.
How can I get more information to debug further?

```
The only log I get when starting `airflow work` is
root@ip-10-0-4-85:~# /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
[2018-07-25 17:49:43,430] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2018-07-25 17:49:43,469] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
[2018-07-25 17:49:43,594] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
Starting flask
[2018-07-25 17:49:43,665] {_internal.py:88} INFO -  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8793/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^C
```

The config I use is the default one with a postgresql and redis backend for celery.
I see the worked online in Flower.

Thanks.

edit: edited for more informations

Comment: edited with more informations for clarity. By worked node I mean a node where the `airflow worker` command is ran. flower is setup on the same node as the webserver and scheduler. Only the worker has a dedicated node.

Comment: If there are no logs from the worker and only Flower is showing you this, make sure that the worker can be reached from the Flower node. Maybe they cannot connect. This seems to me to be a setup issue, firewall issue or a networking issue.

Comment: @bhdup did you figure out what's causing this. I am getting the exact same error for a specific dag. I have other dags in the cluster that have been running normally. Additionally, my scheduled tasks go from `scheduled` from `up_for_retry`the tasks are run manually perpetually stay on `queued`.

Comment: what version of celery are you running?